# I can not connect to the Internet with cable and login window

Tags: networking, server, firefox, internet, ethernet

I am having huge problems with connecting my Ubuntu 20.04 to the Internet.

I live in a student village and to access the Internet you need to log in with your academic email and password. This is the trouble I find.

I plug an Ethernet cable into my laptop. Ubuntu recognizes the ethernet cable and I can connect to it. A window with the error message “Hotspot Login - Error receiving data: Connection reset by peer” appears.

If I open Firefox and type a random website I get “Log in to network - You must log in to this network before you can access the Internet” with a blue button “Open network login page”. If I press the button a new Firefox table opens, with the error “Server not found - Hmmm. We’re having trouble in finding that site”. If I try again I get the same problem.

If I type `ip addr` in Ubuntu terminal I get this:

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 50:7b:9d:d9:cb:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.220.220.253/22 brd 10.220.223.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
valid_lft 3480sec preferred_lft 3480sec
inet6 fe80::e351:a0d7:f128:645d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The `route` command gives me a gateaway IP address xyz, but if I type `ping xyz` I start getting a sequence of lines printed on terminal, where each new line increases the number seq=1,2,…,22,... If I abort the operation I get this.

```
...
From xyz icmp_seq=21 Packet filtered
From xyz icmp_seq=22 Packet filtered
^C
--- xyz ping statistics ---
22 packets transmitted, 0 received, +22 errors, 100% packet loss, time 21041ms
```

I tried different sockets and cables, all of them work with Windows but not with my Ubuntu. Hope I do not have to reinstall Windows in dual boot just to access the Internet. :)

Comment: Consider contacting the network's IT department. They may not realize that their login method is broken for Linux users.

Comment: Another possible workaround is installing Chrome for linux from the deb.  Sometimes that will get to the login when Firefox will not.

Comment: I solved it, thanks! I installed Chrome and going to pages like neverSSL.com it automatically loads the login page. Then everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem in many hotels where the hotel login is not Linux-friendly (I despise them for trying to make a quick buck out of selling an internet connection but this is for another discussion). To overcome this as a temporary measure, connect your cellphone to your computer and establish an Ethernet connection. Login to the network with your cellphone. You should then have a connection. Then do as @user535733 suggests.